# C code runs well with breakpoints but crash without breakpoints

Tags: c

I have a code in c language that is running well if you put breakpoints inside it and walk through it manually, but if we loose the break points and let it run automatically it crashes.

What could this mean?

This is the function:

```
void play(int map[length][length])
{
    FILE*             matrix;
    struct Coordinate startPoint;
    struct Coordinate endPoint;
    char              buffer[200];
    int               lineNumber;
    int               run = 1;
    int               direction;
    int               gaps;
    int               letter;
    int               playerX;
    int               playerY;
    int               killerX;
    int               killerY;

    startPoint.steps = -1;

    printf("enter X and Y of player");
    scanf("%d,%d", &playerX, &playerY);

    printf("enter X and Y of killer");
    scanf("%d,%d", &killerX, &killerY);

    while (run)
    {
        letter = 0;
        printf("enter direction [2]=down, [4]=left, [6]=right, [8]=up");
        scanf("%d", &direction);
        switch (direction)
        {
            case 2: playerX++; break;
            case 4: playerY--; break;
            case 6: playerY++; break;
            case 8: playerX--; break;
        }

        startPoint.x = killerX;
        startPoint.y = killerY;
        endPoint.x   = playerX;
        endPoint.y   = playerY;

        root = insertDataToTree(root, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, map, startPoint.steps);
        findShortestPath(root, startPoint, endPoint);

        matrix = fopen("space.txt", "r");
        for (lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < 15; lineNumber++)
        {
            fgets(buffer, 200, matrix);
        }

        for (gaps = 0; gaps < 4; letter++)
        {
            if (buffer[letter] == ' ')
            {
                gaps++;
            }
        }

        fclose(matrix);

        switch (buffer[letter + 1])
        {
            case 'd': killerY++; break;
            case 'l': killerX--; break;
            case 'r': killerX++; break;
            case 'u': killerY--; break;
        }

        if (playerX == killerX && playerY == killerY)
        {
            run = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i'm gettings:
    Unhandled exception at 0x779615de in Project 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00440000.

Thanks

Comment: And it crashes where exactly?  What is the message?  Basic info please...

Comment: Sorry about that, i added the message. Don't know where it crashes cause when i try to debug it runs well

Comment: what about printf debugging? memory offsets on your machine won't really help us

Comment: You don't check to see if your `scanf()` calls have succeeded.

Comment: It's not really the answer as i enter the same values with and without the breakpoints. It working good with the break points

Comment: If you have [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) installed, run it with the [--tool=exp-sgcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/sg-manual.html) flag over this code.  Meaning, I think you're overwriting non-alloc'd arrays.  Running it w/o the sgcheck flag can't hurt either.

Comment: Inside the debugger, the values may get 0 initialized for you. Whether it is the answer or not, you should check for the success or failure of your function calls, if correct operation depends on the call succeeding.

Comment: Also, the way you are reading your `matrix` file, you're really only ever looking at the last line of the file.... Simple debugging steps, like adding `printf()` to verify variables have the values you expect them to and verifying the return values from calls (`scanf()` especially, but others too) would be a good plan...

Comment: you can use printf debugging to find where exactly your program crashes

Comment: Better not use TABs in C code.

Comment: To add on jxh, the debugger generally uses different memory allocation code than the runtime so sometimes you get memory errors at runtime that you don't get in the debugger. Printf, and perhaps valgrind are possible ways to debug. Although the Answer below is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues, as indicated in the various comments. In summary:

- You don't check to see if your `scanf()` calls have succeeded. This could lead you to use those variables uninitialized.
- The way you are reading from `matrix`, you are only looking at the last `N % 199` bytes of the last line (where the last line is `N` bytes long).

Finally, you may be reading beyond your input buffer in this loop:

```
    for(gaps=0;gaps<4;letter++)
        if(buffer[letter]==' ')
            gaps++;
```

If there are fewer than `4` gaps in the line, you will read beyond the end of the buffer looking for more gaps. You should stop at the end of the string.

```
    for(gaps=0;gaps<4;letter++) {
        if (buffer[letter]=='\0') break;
        if(buffer[letter]==' ')
            gaps++;
    }
```